# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio.rest'; 'twilio' is not a package

Tags: python, twilio, chatbot

from twilio.rest import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twilio.rest'; 'twilio' is not a package

Getting error while trying to use Twilio.
Have already uninstalled and installed twilio

Please help me fix this

I am trying to connect Twilio with my VS Code, it works on google colab but not on VS Code

Comment: I have tried reinstalling Twilio and restarting my system

Comment: Confirm that you have done this:  `pip install twilio` and visited this page:  https://pypi.org/project/twilio/